# ASP.NET Core Tag Helper Checkbox does not save unchecked value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, tag-helpers

I'm adding a checkbox in an MVC form with Tag Helpers:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Billable"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Billable" type="checkbox" />
    <input asp-for="@Model.Billable" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

When the user changes the value to Checked from Unchecked, the form value passed back to the controller is True - perfect.

However, if the value of the checkbox starts as Checked and the user changes it to Unchecked, the form value passed back to the controller is still True???

Comment: It seems like both inputs have same Id `Billable`. Could you rename one different than other?

Comment: I thought I needed the hidden value for the checkbox??  Silly me. I took it off the page and now it saves.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the type is `checkbox`, the input tag helper creates a hidden element for the checkbox for you with the same `name`. If you check the view source of the page, you can see that

```
<input name="Billable" type="hidden" value="false">
```

When user enable/check the checkbox and submit the form, it will send 2 form data item, one for the actual check box with value `True` and the second for the hidden input with value `False`.

If you inspect the network traffic (Chrome devtools->network), you can see this

```
Billable: true
Billable: false
```

When model binder uses this data, it will give precedence to the `True` value and map that to your boolean property.

When user uncheck the checkbox and submit the form, it will send only one form data element, just the one for the hidden input element with value `false` and model binder will set `false` value for your boolean proeprty of your action method parameter.

Your current code is generating the checkbox element and an **additional**  hidden input element with the same name `Billable`. So basically it will render 2 input elements(1 checkbox,1 hidden element which the helper created and 1 you explicitly created). When user unchecks the checkbox, It will send `True` for your explicitly created one and `false` for the one created by the tag helper.

If you inspect the network traffic (Chrome devtools->network), you can see this

```
Billable: True
Billable: false
```

Model binder will use this information and map the value `True` to your Billable property of your view model.

The solution is to remove the extra hidden element and rely on the one created by tag helper.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Billable"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Billable" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with the exact same Razor markup but no `<input type="hidden">` is being rendered for some reason.

Comment: Update to my comment: I found that when I use the `<form>` tag-helper then the `<input type="hidden">` elements are rendered right before the `</form>` close tag. If I don't use the `<form>` tag-helper then the hidden inputs are rendered right after the `<input>` tag-helper rendered `<input />` element.